# Qual o melhor caminho para desenvolver um player de vídeo do zero?

Tags: c#, java

Bom, gostaria de saber quais tópicos, artigos livros enfim referências me ajudariam na tarefa de desenvolver um player de vídeo do zero como o média player classic por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certa vez tive a tarefa no trabalho de criar um video player do zero em `C#`.

Na realidade, o Framework cuidaria da pior parte do trabalho, então só me restaria "implementar" e unir as peças do quebra-cabeças. Hoje eu confesso que `C#` ainda não era o meu forte (e ainda não é), mas como todo bom motorista: dê-me a chave e eu dirigirei.

Hoje vejo que parte do desafio teria sido menor se houvesse o devido planejamento que, inclusive, não era de todo grande, pois, repito, o Framework cuidaria de boa parte da carpinada. Contudo, a esfoliação diária atrás de um objetivo único e dados os curtos prazos que nós profissionais da área somos constantemente submetidos fez-me deliberadamente "decorar" e ter uma visão bem mais analítica e macro da coisa, de modo que você pode considerar este conteúdo como importante para sua caminhada.

**1. Planejamento**

É essencial. Então se você conseguir responder a estas perguntas, parte do esboço do seu objetivo já terá sido resolvida:

- O que o seu video player terá?
- Os controles (`play`, `pause`, `stop`, `forward` e `backward`) serão customizáveis?
- Haverá uma opção `fullscreen`? Qual a posição deste ícone?
- Haverá opção de `legenda`? Esta legenda será escolhida no HD pelo usuário? Esta legenda será utilizada automaticamente se houver um arquivo `.srt` com o mesmo nome do vídeo e na mesma pasta do mesmo?
- Quais os `métodos` desta nova classe?
- Quais os `eventos` desta nova classe? (talvez a mais importante)
- Os `controls` (como propriedades da classe) terão acesso publico (para maior "controle" dos visual dos elementos)?

**2. Propriedades**

As que posso destacar:

- `IsPlayerMounted` (logo após a última linha do método `mountPlayer()`)
- `IsPlayerReady` (logo após carregar o vídeo e ele estar pronto para ação)
- `IsPlaying` (bool)
- `IsPaused` (bool)
- `IsStopped` (bool)
- `IsInFullscreen` (bool)

**3. Métodos**

Os métodos mais comuns, eu já posso te adiantar (e são auto descritivos):

- `MontaPlayer()` (atualiza `IsMounted`)
- `Play()` (atualiza `IsPlaying`, `IsPaused` e `IsStopped`)
- `Pause()` (atualiza is `IsPlaying`, `IsPaused` e `IsStopped`)
- `Stop()` (atualiza is `IsPlaying`, `IsPaused` e `IsStopped`)
- `Backward()`
- `Forward()`
- `Fullscreen()`
- `Destroy()` (atualiza boa parte das propriedades acima)

**4. Eventos**

Talvez a parte mais importante da problemática pois é aonde tudo acontece. "Ao dar play", "ao pausar", "ao parar", "ao dar fullscreen", *timming* é tudo num player de vídeo. Você certamente não ia querer um `delay` ao dar play ou que o botão `play` demore a aparecer após dar `pause` ou `stop`, certo? Então implementar alguns eventos com `delegates` apropriados tornam o aplicativo de video player mais rico e com mais recursos.

Alguns eventos que utilizei (são auto descritíveis):

- `OnMount()`
- `OnReady()` (util para implementar uma propriedade `autoPlay = true` por exemplo ou mesmo `autoFullSreenOnPlay = true` por exemplo)
- `OnPlay()`
- `OnPause()`
- `OnStop()`
- `OnDestroy()`

**5. Diagrama de sequência**

Aqui, esboçado de maneira grosseira:

() Usuário carrega o video -> classe monta os controles visuais (moldura, controles do vídeo) -> classe carrega o video no controle correspondente (ex.: `MediaElement` no `WPF`) -> tela fullscreen (se aplicável) -> video é iniciado (se `AutoPlayOnReady = true`) -> inicia legenda (se aplicável)

**6. Screenshot**

Abaixo algumas screenshots da ideia toda implementada:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Conclusão**

A maior parte do trabalho é de fato fazer com que as peças se encaixem. Seja qual for a linguagem que você escolher, o conceito será sempre o mesmo.